# Target device disappears from the selected target device WHLK

Tags: c++, windows, testing, device-driver

I am doing **DTM** testing of some driver project for `win10` using **WHLK**. I've followed all the steps and have installed client at Test PC.

When I put the tests and check the progress, immediately the target and the selected tests are getting disappeared from the list and in that current project

I am unable to add target device again it gives error. So I've to create a new project and select a target device again and has to repeat all those step again to put the tests. 
And when I put the other project on test it takes too much time to start the tests.

What is the problem?
Why is the target getting disappeared? How can I get it back? Any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem behind the delay in starting the test in new project is the previous project in which the target got disappeared.

Actually the tests are still going on even if the target is missing in selected devices list and your new project is getting into the queue.

It may be a bug in **WHLK** or some other problem that device getting disappeared.

When the tests will be completed from old project after that only your new project tests will be started.

There is a **solution** to get back the target device in selected target list.
If this problem occurs you just need to close the **WHLK and the HLK manager** and **restart** both and then check out the project you will get your selected target back in the list. It worked for me.

If you have removed the old project just wait to finish the tests or manually close them in test PC.